# Is it a bug in DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

In version 13 on Windows 10 I solve

```
DSolve[{y''[x]*y[x] + 5*y[x]^6*y'[x]^4 == 2*y'[x]^2, y[1] == 1, y'[1] == 1}, y[x], x]
```

> `{}`

and a warning

> DSolve::bvnul: "For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution."

The problem under consideration does have a solution `y[x_] := (4 x - 3)^(1/4)` and Maple finds it.
As far as I understand it, the general solution is produced by

```
DSolve[y''[x]*y[x] + 5*y[x]^6*y'[x]^4 == 2*y'[x]^2, y[x], x]
```

> `{{y[x] ->  InverseFunction[-(( Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), -(1/10), 9/10, -(#1^10/C[1])] Sqrt[ C[1] + #1^10])/(#1 Sqrt[1 + #1^10/C[1]])) &][x + C[2]]}, {y[ x] -> InverseFunction[( Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), -(1/10), 9/10, -(#1^10/C[1])] Sqrt[ C[1] + #1^10])/(#1 Sqrt[1 + #1^10/C[1]]) &][x + C[2]]}}`

Is `{}` a bug or I incorrectly  understand it?

Comment: The ODE under consideration can be reduced to Riccati, making use of standard methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Symbolic algebra is, generically speaking, only generically true: Sometimes the solution space as given by a formula is missing a hypermanifold that is contained in the closure of the solution space. Frequently the missing boundary may be found as `C[1] -> Infinity`, but in this case a missing hypermanifold is given by `C[1] == 0` in the general solution `gensol` below. (The output is long, but it divides by `C[1]` in a few places, which makes clear that solutions with `C[1] == 0` are missing.) Usually the missing solutions may be computed as limits, provided `Limit[]` can be evaluated.

```
ode = y''[x]*y[x] + 5*y[x]^6*y'[x]^4 == 2*y'[x]^2;
ics = {y[1] == 1, y'[1] == 1};
gensol = DSolve[ode, y[x], x];

toPureFunc = # /. HoldPattern[y_[x__] -> body_] :>
  y -> Function[{x}, body] &;
sols = Map[(* compute limit sols for C[1] -> 0: *)
    FullSimplify@Limit[#, C[1] -> 0] &,
    gensol /.  (* convert to implicit equation: *)
     {HoldPattern[{y_[x_] -> InverseFunction[f_][a_]}] :>
       Inactive[Solve][f[y[x]] == a, y[x]]},
    {3}] //    (* solve for all branches: *)
   Activate // (* <- gives Solve::nongen warning: *)
   Apply[Join] //
   DeleteDuplicates // (* pick valid sols: *)
   Pick[#, Simplify[ode /. toPureFunc[#]]] &;
With[ (* find sols for which C[1] -> 0 is valid in IVP: *)
 {icsols = Solve /@ (ics /. toPureFunc[sols])},
  Pick[
   Join @@ MapThread[ReplaceAll, {sols, icsols}],
   Replace[icsols, {{} | _Solve -> False, _ -> True}, 1]
   ] //
  Simplify
 ]
```

> `Solve::nongen`: There may be values of the parameters for which some or all solutions are not valid.
> `Solve::nongen`: There may be values....
>
> ```
> {{y[x] -> (-3 + 4 x)^(1/4)}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the workaround. Frankly speaking,  I don't understand it (A good code is a commented code.). BTW, Maple produces a quite simple implicit general solution without  `Hypergeometric2F1` .

Comment: Could you explain, in particular, what `Replace[icsols, {{} | _Solve -> False, _ -> True}, 1]]` does?

Comment: @user64494 I don't get Maple, but different softwares with secret methods probably can give different results. 2nd comment: `icsols` is the results of `Solve` on the IVP for all branches of the gen. sol. A result can be no sol. `{}`, unable to solve `Solve[...]` (original command), solutions `{{<rules>},...}`, or a sol. with a "full dimensional" component `{{}}``. The `{{}}` does not happen here; whether it indicates a valid sol. of the IVP or not is irrelevant. The results in `icsols` are replaced by `True` or `False` according to whether there was a sol. of the IVP or not, respectively.

Comment: Thank you. Methods of ODE symbolic  solving are not secret.